# How to transport fishes over a short distance/less than one hour?

Tags: aquarium

I wanted to make sure that I figured out the best way to transport fish (e.g. wels, guppies which less than 5 cm body length) for less than 1 hour.

I assume that it's no necessary to provide additional oxygen as suggested in [How to transport fishes over large distance?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1671/how-to-transport-fishes-over-large-distance), so the only (consequent) question is imo whether it's better to use a static container (e.g. a bucket) or a plastic/other impermeable bag. A static container causes more movement of the water (surface) whereas a bag has the disadvantage to change the depth of the water dramatically if it falls to the side. Both is stressful.

Stores usually use plastic bags, but that might be because they don't have to be returned and that doesn't necessarily mean that it's the best option.

I assume that it's better that it's dark inside the container because it calms the fish down. It might be bad, though, because the change between shutting down the circulation in the dark and waking it up if the container moves might be more stressful than keeping the fish awake/stressed constantly.

Answer (score 2):

For that distance just about anything large enough is going to be fine, bag, bucket, large tupperware, without oxygen or other method to keep the water oxygenated. The exception to this would be very large fish, which isn't what you're dealing with. Keeping the container in something dark will additionally help to reduce stress. Unless the road you are traveling on is extremely rough, I wouldn't be especially concerned with the movement in the bag being harmful to the fish. The water offers excellent padding to anything in it as long as it's not literally getting shaken up.

Comment: Unless it's a particularly delicate fish, like a betta, in which case being on the road can be just bad. Just for any Joe reading this in the future with a flappy-finny fish...